# How to integrate @2x @3x images to React Native Project (Both Android & IOS)?

Tags: android, reactjs, image, react-native, resolution

I had added the same image's versions (@2x @3x)into src>asssets to work our platform in all devices. Here is the problem, VSCode only recognizes i.e path.png (it doesnt recognize @2x and @3x). How can we deal with this problem?

Comment: but why do you need 3 resolution of the same image in a mobile app?

Comment: Because the resolution of each phone is different. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio

Answer (score 26):

React native automatically pick up the desired image from the 3 options available i.e. 
**1x, 2x, 3x**. We just have to provide the filename for the base image.

**Example**

```
.
├── button.js
└── img
    ├── check.png
    ├── check@2x.png
    └── check@3x.png
```

So, as stated above, when you have to use check image, just provide the image path for check.png and the rest will be automatically taken care by react native according to device screen density for both android and ios devices.
Use the image just like below and everything works like a charm.

```
<Image source={require('./img/check.png')} />
```

> More you can read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images) about the images from react native
>   official docs.

I hope this helps.... Thanks :)

Comment: Firstly, thank you. The things I do and the things you write are exactly the same. However, the screen density is different on some phones.

Comment: so, where are you stuck @chc ??.....vscode not recognising the 2x and 3x?